# How to pass Kinesis Firehose data to dynamodb table?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

A Kinesis Firehose stream receives messages.
There is an option to persist into S3, but my use case is to insert into dynamodb table.
Firehose has an option to enable Lambda function. Shall i write insert logic into dynamodb table using Lambda? Is this the right approach?
If so, then how to insert records into DynamoDB using Lambda written in Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't a standard way of inserting Firehose stream data into DynamoDB (such as S3 or Redshift). The recommended way is to do a Lambda and insert the records into DynamoDB with that.

Use `dynamoDB.batchWriteItem` or `dynamoDB.putItem`, more info in this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/batch-operation-document-api-java.html) or [this one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPIItemCRUD.html).

```
public String handleRequest(KinesisFirehoseEvent event, Context context)
    List<KinesisFirehoseEvent.Record> records = event.getRecords();
    for(KinesisFirehoseEvent.Record rec : records)
    {
        String recordId = rec.getRecordId();
        String data = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(rec.getData()).toString();

        Item item = transformStringToItem(data);
        // Write the item to the table 
        table.putItem(item);
    }
    return "success";
}
```

The firehoseStream structure is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-kinesisfirehose.html), and a Java example example is [here](https://github.com/qyjohn/LambdaTransform/blob/master/src/main/java/net/qyjohn/firehose/FirehoseTransformer.java), and more info on firehose to lambda [here](https://www.waitingforcode.com/data-aws/aws-kinesis-firehose-event-time-batch-layer/read).

Comment: .thanks for your inputs.. The example which you shared is client program. How can i deploy into into aws.. Or call the functionalities from Lamba.. How can i do that.. Please advise. since i new to aws

Comment: Lambda should look the same, basically it takes the stream by input and does a put/write on Dynamodb, will provide soon a code sample

Comment: Thanks .. Please share. i am waiting

Comment: @LearnHadoop updated the code, it's more of a direction, but please adapt it to your needs

Comment: This isn't quite correct. The only "integration" Firehose has with Lambda is as a "transform" step, and it must return "Ok" or "Dropped" in the `result` response, in addition to the transformed data. It looks like this may be from a Kinesis **Stream** example rather than a Kinesis **Firehose** example. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-kinesisfirehose.html