# AWS Kinesis Firehose to DynamoDB through AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I am creating an architecture where Producers sends data to AWS Kinesis Firehose. I need to store the data into DynamoDB through AWS Kinesis. According to [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-name.html), DynamoDB is not supported as one of the destinations. Is it possible to use Lambda Function to store the data into DynamoDB? In that case, what should I mention the destination as?
I'd highly appreciate a response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass Kinesis Firehose data to dynamodb table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58351730/how-to-pass-kinesis-firehose-data-to-dynamodb-table)

Comment: It doesn't answer my question entirely as it does not mention what has to be mentioned as Destination while setting Kinesis Firehose

Comment: @Ronnie, the destination needs to be an HTTP endpoint. The HTTP endpoint needs to point to an AWS Lambda function. The AWS Lambda function needs to write to DynamoDB.